# Identity theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The following is the identity theorem in complex analysis:

> Let $f,g:U\to\Bbb C$ be holomorphic functions with $U\subset\Bbb C$ open and connected, if $f\lvert_A=g\lvert_A$ where $A\subset U$ is a set with an accumulation point in $U$, then $f=g$.

Is there a version of this theorem that works in complex Banach spaces or Banach algebras? I think this should be standard knowledge, but internet searches aren't helpful.

One idea to reduce to the other case would be "lay in" one dimensional subspaces in $U$ and then compose the difference of $f-g$ with an element of the dual space. This would be a differentiable function with an accumulation point at which it evaluates to zero. Doing it for arbitrary affine 1d subspaces and linear functionals would be enough to see $f=g$ on all of $U$.

However unless $U$ is convex the domain of this guy need not be connected and unless $f-g=0$ on an *open* subset there is no guarantee that every point in $U$ lies on an affine subspace that has an accumulation point on which we know $f-g=0$.

Comment: You should be careful to say $A\subset U$ is a set with an accumulation point ->in $U$<-

Comment: @zhw. thank you, very right. I have edited the post.

Comment: Oh and by the way, $U$ being convex is not a restriction, since if $U$ is path connected you can cover a path between any two points via a finite amount of balls (which are all convex and have open convex intersections).

Comment: Are you asking about Banach-space valued holomorphic functions on a domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, or are you asking about functions defined on a domain in a higher-dimensional space?

Comment: With domain in a higher dimensional space. I think the other case follows simply from looking at $x^*\circ f$ where $x^*$ are elements from the dual, right?

Comment: That works for domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$. For higher-dimensional domains, things are more complicated. The "having an accumulation point in $U$" doesn't even suffice for $U \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ any more (consider $f(z,w) = z\cdot w$).

Comment: @DanielFischer so for the identity theorem one needs something like an open set where the functions coincide, my sketch in the post would work I think for this case. This seems very strong though, is there an example of a nowhere dense set in $\Bbb C^2$ on which the theorem holds?

Comment: If $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a domain and $0\in U$, then $f\lvert_{U\cap \mathbb{R}^n} = 0$ implies $f \equiv 0$. The zero sets of non-constant holomorphic functions are still small, but if the dimension of the domain is larger than $1$, zeros are no longer isolated. The zero set of a nonconstant holomorphic function is a one-*co*dimensional complex submanifold at most points.